# Selecting an node by attribute with Goutte / Symfony CssSelector component

Tags: phpunit, functional-testing, goutte

I'm using [Goutte](https://github.com/fabpot/Goutte) (which is a standalone package of the Symfony functional testing components) to test a Wordpress theme:

```
public function testDocumentHasBasicNodes(){
    $this->assertEquals(1, $this->crawler->filter('title')->count(),
            'document shall have a TITLE node');

    $this->assertEquals(1, $this->crawler->filter('meta')->count(),
            'document shall have a meta[charset="utf-8"] node');
}
```

The first test passes but:

```
indexTest::testDocumentHasBasicNodes
document shall have a meta[charset="utf-8"] node
Failed asserting that 0 matches expected 1.
```

**So to sum up my question:**
How do I get a node by attribute with Goutte / Symfony CSS Selector component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may filter by attribute like this.

```
$this->assertEquals(1, $this->crawler->filter('meta[charset="utf-8"]')->count(),
    'document shall have a meta[charset="utf-8"] node');
```